# utility method like ActiveSupport#try in ruby that returns a default value if method undefined

Tags: ruby, activesupport

I sometimes use `#try` from `ActiveSupport`:

```
1.try(:not_a_method)
#=> nil
```

Yaay! No exceptions thrown, but let's say I don't want nil:

```
1.better_than_try(:not_a_method){0}
#=> 0
```

Does this exist?

Comment: You could always write your own core extension called `try_or_whatever`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `||` operator when you want return something instead of `nil`:

```
1.try(:not_a_method) || 0
#=> 0
```

Comment: The one caveat here is this will stomp `false` values and any method that legitimately returns `nil`.